# Why two empty files have different md5sum?

Tags: md5sum

```
touch toto.txt
md5sum toto.txt
a4f004eb028c83dea918471ad5939cfa 
touch titi.txt
md5sum titi.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

And i don't understand why, the two files are empty and should be the same no ?

Comment: Only the second one is empty. If the file already exists, `touch` will only update its date, it will not truncate the file to zero length.

Comment: @dratenik you are right ! two empty files have the same hash and toto.txt was not empty.